# Disaster recovery/failover for Azure log analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, disaster-recovery

I am trying to find a way to plan failover/Disaster Recovery for log analytics workspace.
I went through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-create-workspace  and I don't see any solution to export workspace data for disaster recovery. Is below only possible way ?
https://www.borninthecloud.com/exporting-log-analytics-data-to-blob-store/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides that, there are other ways to do that:

1.Use the [Azure Log Analytics REST API](https://dev.loganalytics.io/) to fetch the data, then stores the data.

2.Use Azure Automation Runbook. For more details, you can refer to this [article](https://blog.tyang.org/2019/06/30/azure-automation-runbook-to-export-data-from-multiple-log-analytics-workspaces/).

3.In azure portal -> the Log Analytics workspace -> Logs tab, write a query to fetch the specified data, then click the "Export" button, screenshot as below:

[image]